# Hardhat Error HH306: The '--config' parameter of task 'help' expects a value, but none was passed

Tags: solidity, ether, hardhat, ethereumjs

I have been doing smart contract development using hardhat. I am trying to do create a config of the empty project using `yarn hardhat --config` as standard command `yarn hardhat`  is not working for configuring the empty project

I am facing this error in running the hardhat command after installing hardhat in the project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Do `yarn init -y` first and then `yarn add --dev hardhat`
Both pointing to your project directory